# PayPal doesn't capture payment after subscription is created - React

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are using PayPal in order to enable subscription in our platform.
I set up the product and plans inside PayPal and integrated the "PayPal Smart Buttons" using the "react-smart-payment-buttons" package (https://github.com/erksch/react-smart-payment-buttons).

I managed to create the subscription successfully but the first payment is not captured immediately or at all.

When I'm using the PayPal Subscription API in order the see when will be the next billing cycle, it shows a timestamp that has already passed.

For example, this is part of the JSON I got from the API:

```
"billing_info": {
        "outstanding_balance": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "0.0"
        },
        "cycle_executions": [
            {
                "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
                "sequence": 1,
                "cycles_completed": 0,
                "cycles_remaining": 12,
                "current_pricing_scheme_version": 1
            }
        ],
        "next_billing_time": "2019-07-01T10:00:00Z",
        "failed_payments_count": 0
    },
    "auto_renewal": false,
    "create_time": "2019-07-01T15:34:02Z"
}
```

As you can see, the `next_billing_time` value is before the `create_time` which doesn't make sense.

What I already did:
After the user approves the subscription, I'm getting the ID of the order and also the subscription. When trying to capture the payment by using the PayPal Payments API and the order id I got, I'm getting back an error.
I checked the status of the created subscription and it shows ACTIVE.

```
createSubscription(data, actions) {
    let plan_id = process.env.REACT_APP_PAY_PAL_BASIC_PLAN_ID;
    return actions.subscription.create({
        plan_id
    });
}

onApprove(data, actions) {
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = process.env.REACT_APP_UPGRADE_USER_URL;
    Http.open("POST", url);
    Http.setRequestHeader("x-access-token", this.state.token);
    Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    Http.send(`plan=${this.state.plan}&subscriptionId=${data.subscriptionID}`);
}
```

I'll be happy if someone can assist me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. This new API, while looking good in docs, basically seem to be working like Billing Agreements under the hood (I'm pretty sure it is actually using BA under the hood). There is no option to capture the funds at the moment of sub activation. You can add a "setup fee" which will be "collected" within minutes after activation but how the recurring payment works after that is still a mistery to me. What is more, web ui for managing recurring payments fails with a lengthy error when trying to open details of subs created using the new API.

Comment: I managed to change the `next_billing_time` by adding the `start_time` key with the value of tomorrow at 10:00 UTC. Currently, I'm waiting to see if it will capture the money as it supposed to do. I'll update.